# Is this a typo in Bash manual's redirection section?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

```
Note that the order of redirections is significant.  For example, the command

          ls > dirlist 2>&1

   directs both standard output and standard error to the file dirlist, 
   while the command

          ls 2>&1 > dirlist

   directs  only  the  standard  output  to  file  dirlist,  because the 
   standard error was duplicated from the standard output before the standard
   output was redirected to dirlist.
```

Now, that last part is confusing to me.  In that case, any standard error would be printed to the terminal and any STDOUT would go to the dirlist file.  That is what would happen, but that is not how I understand the manual.

It seems like it should say "because the standard error was duplicated from the standard output AFTER the standard output was redirected to dirlist".  If STDERR was sent to STDOUT before STDOUT was directed to a file, then wouldn't the file contain STDOUT AND STDERR?

Can someone please clear this up for me?  Is it just poor reading comprehension on my part?  The use of the word duplication seems a little strange to me in this context.  Perhaps that is throwing me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/14615653/1030675

Comment: A classic case of mixing up operations that are "by value" vs "by reference".  When you duplicate a file descriptor it is a *by value* operation.  In programming, after `a = 1; b = a; a = 2` you expect `a == 2 && b == 1` to be true.  The redirection `2>&1` is similar to the `b = a` assignment - it is by value, not by reference.  `2>&1` does not wed file descriptor 2 to file descriptor 1 for all of eternity - they are still 2 distinct file descriptors, who happen to point to the same file.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Duplication* is really the important part here.

Let's see where the file descriptors are going to before redirection. This is normally the current terminal, e.g.:

```
STDOUT ---> /dev/pts/1
STDERR ---> /dev/pts/1
```

Now, if we call `ls -l` without redirection, output and error messages go to my terminal under `/dev/pts/1`.

If we first redirect the `STDOUT` to a file (`ls -l > dirlist`), it looks like this:

```
STDOUT ---> /home/bon/dirlist
STDERR ---> /dev/pts/1
```

When we *then* redirect `STDERR` to a *duplicate* of `STDOUT`'s file descriptor (`ls -l > dirlist 2>&1`), `STDERR` goes to a duplicate of `/home/bon/dirlist`:

```
STDOUT ---> /home/bon/dirlist
STDERR ---> /home/bon/dirlist
```

If we would *first* redirect `STDERR` to a duplicate of `STDOUT`'s file descriptor (`ls -l 2>&1`):

```
STDOUT ---> /dev/pts/1
STDERR ---> /dev/pts/1
```

and *then* `STDOUT` to a file (`ls -l 2>&1 > dirlist`), we would get this:

```
STDOUT ---> /home/bon/dirlist
STDERR ---> /dev/pts/1
```

Here, `STDERR` is still going to the terminal.

You see, the order in the man page is correct.

---

### Testing Redirection

Now, you can test that yourself. Using `ls -l /proc/$$/fd/`, you see where `STDOUT` (with fd 1) and `STDERR` (with fd 2), are going for the current process:

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd/
total 0
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 18:19 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 18:19 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 07:41 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 18:19 255 -> /dev/pts/1
```

Let's create a small shell script that shows where your file descriptors are pointed. This way, we always get the state when calling `ls`, including any redirection from the calling shell.

```
$ cat > lookfd.sh
#!/bin/sh
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/
^D
$ chmod +x lookfd.sh
```

(With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, you send an end-of-file and so stop the `cat` command reading from `STDIN`.)

Now, call this script with varying combinations of redirection:

```
$ ./lookfd.sh 
total 0
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:08 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:08 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:08 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:08 255 -> /home/bon/lookfd.sh
$ ./lookfd.sh > foo.out
$ cat foo.out 
total 0
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 1 -> /home/bon/foo.out
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 255 -> /home/bon/lookfd.sh
$ ./lookfd.sh 2>&1 > foo.out
$ cat foo.out 
total 0
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 1 -> /home/bon/foo.out
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:10 255 -> /home/bon/lookfd.sh
$ ./lookfd.sh > foo.out 2>&1
$ cat foo.out 
total 0
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:11 0 -> /dev/pts/1
l-wx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:11 1 -> /home/bon/foo.out
l-wx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:11 2 -> /home/bon/foo.out
lr-x------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:11 255 -> /home/bon/lookfd.sh
```

You can see, that the file descriptors 1 (for `STDOUT`) and 2 (for `STDERR`) vary. For fun, you could also redirect `STDIN` and see the result:

```
$ ./lookfd.sh < /dev/zero
total 0
lr-x------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:18 0 -> /dev/zero
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:18 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:18 2 -> /dev/pts/1
lr-x------ 1 bon bon 64 Jul 24 19:18 255 -> /home/bon/lookfd.sh
```

(Question left to the reader: Where does file descriptor 255 point? ;-))

Comment: +1 - excellent answer. Extremely well written and terrific examples. Thank you!!!

Comment: I see, I think my misunderstanding was that the redirection would be persistent for all following commands, so that any STDERR for the rest of the line would go to STDOUT.

Answer (score 2):

No, the manual is right.

If at first 1 points to the terminal, and 2 also to the terminal, then:

```
command  2>&1   1>somewhere
```

redirection evaluatino will happen from left to right.

So it will FIRST evaluate `2>&1`, and thus FIRST copy what fd `1` used to point to (ie, the file descriptor of `the terminal`, usually /dev/tty) into fd `2`.

So at that point fd `2` now points to where fd `1` used to point to (`the terminal`)

And THEN it evaluates the `1>somewhere` part, and thus will copy the file descriptor of `somewhere` in fd `1` (so at that point, fd `1` now points to `somewhere`, and fd `2` still points to `the terminal`)

So it does indeed print 1 into "somewhere" and 2 into the terminal, as 2 was duplicated from 1 BEFORE 1 has been changed.

The other order:

```
command  1>somewhere 2>&1
```

will first redirect fd `1` to `somewhere`, and then copy that same reference into fd 2, so at the end 2 also points to `somewhere`.
But they are not "linked" from now on. Each can still be redirected separately.

ex:

```
command  1>somewhere 2>&1
exec 2>/dev/null
```

At the end of that one, fd `1` points to `somewhere`, and fd `2` is directed to `/dev/null`

Usual names for fd `1` is STDOUT (standard output), and usual name for fd `2` is STDERR (standard error, as it's commonly used to display errors without interfering with STDOUT)

Comment: @Michael-mrozek : thanks for the edit, but I insist on saying "copy" instead of "duplicate" as "duplicate" could lead one to believe that from now on both are "the same thing", which is not true. ex:  `cmd 1>somewhere 2>&1 ; exec 2>/dev/null` : after the exec, only 2 has been redirected to /dev/null (1 is still going to "somewhere"). I do need help to come up with a way to say "what 1 points to" instead of "the fd 1", however... as that is also confusing...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; [you're the one](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/84291/revisions) who changed it from "copy" to "duplicate". All I did was capitalize and format things, I didn't change a word

Comment: doh... ^^ sorry. And I edited again to reformulate to make more precise what is copied into what ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think the confusing part here is the misapprehension that redirecting stderr to stdout actually connects the two streams.

A perfectly reasonable idea but what happens when you write `2>&1` is stderr takes a peekaboo at what stdout is writing to and writes to the same place itself. Therefore if you subsequently tell stdout to go write somewhere else it has no effect on the destination of stderr which has already been moved.

I think it's a tad counterintuitive myself but that's how it works. Set up where you want to write to first then tell everyone "copy me". 
Hope that clarifies...

Answer (score 0):

**DUPLICATION...**

is important, but rather in the sense that it is the **source of much confusion**. It is really quite simple. This answer is just a "radical" illustration.

The accepted answer is good, but too long and it emphasizes "duplicatition".

The Q wisely ends with:

> The **use of the word duplication** seems a little strange to me in
>   this context. Perhaps that is throwing me.

I use bash notation and define variables "one" and "two" as filehandles "1" and "2". The (output) redirection operator `>` is an assignment `=`. `&` and `$` mean "value" of.

The man bash examples (with default "1" added)

```
ls 1>dirlist 2>&1      # both to dirlist
ls 2>&1 1>dirlist      # 1 to dirlist, 2 stays on tty/screen
```

become:

```
one=dirlist  two=$one
```

and

```
two=$one   one=dirlist
```

And even this is non-automatic to me, and some others I guess. The first line leaves you with `$one` and `$two` both containing "dirlist". Of course.

The second line starts with a useless assignment. Both start by definition with "TTY" (a bit symbolic) as their *direction*; no value is changed by this assignment, and with variables as with filehandles, nothing is magically linked. Variable `two` is not affected by the following `one=dirlist`. Of course not.

Sombody here (6 years ago) suggested "point to" instead of "copy" or "duplicate", and then realized: that would be confusing too.

This duplication or pointer semantic is not even needed. Maybe it's the ampersand that needs more attention. The "value of" operator/token/whatever.

If - and only if - you are looking for a way to get a surprising job number on your *console*, then a "done" message plus as a bonus a file named "2", then you go:

```
ls 1>2& 2>/dev/null
```

It reads naturally as "*copy"/"duplicate" 1 to 2, and then both together to null*. But the idea is wrong, and also the syntax. (but no syntax error, it is valid)

The right way to plan it is to redirect any of the two to null, and then redirect the OTHER to the SAME place:

```
ls 1>/dev/null 2>&1
# or 
ls 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

(the leading "1" can be left away)

(OK the acc. A is not too long, but is too much of a list - or: very good visualisation, not so good explanation)